# P-NP related problems

Tags: computer-science, np-complete

This is a question on a practice final.

> Which of the following statements are true? If it is false, what is the underlying reason behind that?

> I. *If 3-CNF-SAT is in P, then Clique is also in P*.

> II. *For decision problems $L_{1}, L_{2}$ in NP, if P is not NP, $L_{1}$ is at least as hard as $L_{2}$, and $L_{2}$ is at least as hard as $L_{1}$, then $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are NP-complete*.

> III. *For decision problems $L_{1}, L_{2}$ in NP-complete, if $L_{1}$ is not in P, then $L_{2}$ is also not in P*

We are told that only the third statement is True, but there's no explanation why on the key. I have tried to figure this out, and the only conclusion I've come to is:

(I) cannot be true because if A is polynomially reducible to B, this implies B is at least as hard as A, not vice-versa (Not sure if this is a correct conclusion, so feedback on this would be appreciated.)

---

This is the first time I'm learning about the notion of hardness, so I don't understand most of the technical explanations I've found. Any clarifications on why I, II is incorrect, and why III is correct would be appreciated.

Self study I've done includes reading multiple StackExchange posts, multiple Wiki pages, and the corresponding section in the Cormen book. I just personally understand concepts better if I see different explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is true. 3-cnf-sat and clique are both NP-complete. This means that they are reducible to each other. Therefore, if 3-cnf-sat is in P, then P = NP and clique is also in P.

2 is false. The two problems might not be NP-hard. For example, both problems are in P and reduce to each other.

3 is true. If the two problems are NP complete, then they reduce to each other, so one of them is in P iff the other one is.

Comment: Nice, thank you indeed!